# Create a new array from existing hash based on a keys value

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hash

```
[{"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"21315"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"6401"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"6649"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"4974"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"4108"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"16842"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"4987"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"5716"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"6292"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"4894"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"24849"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"5303"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"5753"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"5136"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"4699"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-18", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"11806"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-18", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"5147"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-18", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"5426"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-18", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"5110"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-18", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"4534"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-19", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"8086"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-19", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"1753"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-19", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"2201"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-19", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"1341"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-19", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"1052"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-20", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"5160"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-20", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"2690"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-20", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"2663"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-20", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"1554"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-20", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"1536"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-21", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"2202"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-21", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"860"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-21", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"1004"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-21", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"1238"},
 {"date"=>"2020-09-21", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"954"}]
```

I need to pull out this dataset/hash/array from the above hash:

Logic:
Grab an array that lists the count keys values for each work_category row that matches the provided work_category key value of  “CASE PICKS” for every date listed (maintaining the date order oldest -> newest).

Desired Result Set:

```
[ “21315”, “16842”, “24849”, “11806”, “8086”, “5160”, “2202” ]
```

Seems basic but I'm having some troubles... very green to Ruby. Anyone that could provide some help -- it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your result is supposed to be a hash not an array? Your "desired result set" actually isn't valid Ruby - hashes have keys and values, remember.

Comment: Sorry -- a new array. You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, filter the items with [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and then extract just the counts with [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

```
counts = arr
  .select { |item| item["work_category"] == "CASE PICKS" }
  .map { |item| item["count"] }
```

Answer (score 5):

The following is a sub-array of the array given in the question.

```
arr = [
  {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"21315"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"6401"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"6649"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"4974"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-15", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"4108"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"16842"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"4987"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"PALLET STAGING", "count"=>"5716"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"PUTAWAY", "count"=>"6292"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-16", "work_category"=>"RECEIVING", "count"=>"4894"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"CASE PICKS", "count"=>"24849"},
  {"date"=>"2020-09-17", "work_category"=>"LOADING", "count"=>"5303"}
]
```

It is only necessary to make a single pass through the array.

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |h,arr|
  arr << h["count"] if h["work_category"] == "CASE PICKS"
end
  #=> ["21315", "16842", "24849"]
```

Comment: This is probably a bit more efficient on memory and CPU.